# Push items to array when variable is done being totaled

Tags: javascript, angular, http

Using Angular, I have created a component that fires an initial web request along with two others used in loops. I am looping through these items to set `siteCount` which is declared in the first loop's request. I am using `setTimeout()` to push the totaled amount to an array, however this is probably not best practice.

```
  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public chart: ChartDetails) {

    this.http.get(`https://siteurl.com/items?$filter=Hub/Title eq 'Project Hub' and Active eq 'Yes'`).subscribe(data => {
      data['value'].forEach(item => {
        let siteCount: number = 0
        this.http.get(`${item.Site}/lists/?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 171`).subscribe(data => {

          data['value'].forEach(list => {
            this.http.get(`${item.Site}/lists(guid'${list.Id}')/items`).subscribe(data => {
              this.myTasks = data['value']

              this.myTasks.forEach(variable => {
                variable.internalListName = list.EntityTypeName.replace("List", "")
              });

              siteCount += data['value'].length
            })
          });

        })

        setTimeout(() => {
          if (siteCount) {
            this.chart.goalChartLabels.push(item.Title)
            this.chart.goalChartData.push(siteCount)
          }
        }, 500);

      });
    })

  }
```

Without using `setTimeout`, how can I push `item.Title` and `siteCount` when `siteCount` is done being totaled and before being reset to 0 for the next item?

Comment: Use promises and `Promise.all()` to perform an action when all the promises are resolved.

Comment: @Barmar Or OP can use `forkJoin` if they'd like to continue using `Observable`s

Answer (score 0):

My initial version would look like this:

```js
import { zip } from 'rxjs';

...

   this.http.get(`https://siteurl.com/items?$filter=Active eq 'Yes'`).subscribe(data => {
      data['value'].forEach(item => {
        this.http.get(`${item.Site}/lists/?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 171`).subscribe(data => {
          const itemListObservables = data['value']
            .map(list => this.http.get(`${item.Site}/lists(guid'${list.Id}')/items`));
          zip(...itemListObservables)
            .subscribe(itemLists => {
              const totalCount = itemLists
                .map(l => l.length)
                .reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0)
              if (totalCount > 0) {
                this.chart.goalChartLabels.push(item.Title)
                this.chart.goalChartData.push(totalCount)
              }

              itemLists.forEach(variable => {
                variable.internalListName = list.EntityTypeName.replace("List", "");
                this.myTasks.push(variable);
              });
            });
        })
      });
    })
```

`zip` function waits for all observables to emit a value and returns an array of them.

As for best practices:

1. HttpService calls should be done at least in ngOnInit. You will probably use inputs for running these requests and they won't be defined in constructor.
2. Making three-level nested loops with HTTP requests on each level is not pretty. Consider making this a single resource on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `forkJoin()` to make all the requests and then get the response.

[The rxjs docs link.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)